# Scala Swing ComboBox Editable

Tags: scala, scala-swing

A simple question (but can't find any answer nonetheless :(). Java's Swing has an editable property for the [`ComboBox`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) so user can type to find the value. I check Scala's `ComboBox` implementation, and there is an editable [property](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.swing.ComboBox).

So the question is, how can I set the `ComboBox`'s editable to true (or false) in Scala's Swing?

Thanks before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [makeEditable](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/swing/scala/swing/ComboBox.scala#L201) method, but I can't find any inverse method so you have to use underlying component (scala swing is just a thin wrapper over java swing) to set editability to false:

```
mycombo.peer.setEditable(false)
```

Comment: Ah, can't believe I miss that. Thank you very much!

Comment: For some reason when I do this the combo box is still editable. Is there anything else that could be overriding it?